# Banach contraction theorem exercise

Tags: functions

Use Banach contraction theorem to find a solution of x+e^x=0 correct to 3 decimal places.

Any suggestions how I should begin? Banach contraction theorem is new to me.

Comment: You usually apply the banach contraction theorem to solve equations, so there is an equals sign $(=)$ missing. Are you sure you didn't mistype the question?

Comment: Yes. I corrected it now.

Comment: Using MathJax can improve formatting. For example, $x+e^x=0$ rather than x+e^x=0.

Answer (score 1):

Banach's contraction theorem tells you, that given an operator $\Phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, a solution to the equation

$$\Phi(x)=x$$

can be approximated by fixed point iterations if $\Phi$ is a contraction. To apply this here, we can rewrite the equation

$$x+e^x = 0$$

as

$$x=-e^x$$.

The map $\Phi$ is therefore $\Phi(x)=-e^x$. Now we can take an initial guess for the solution $x_0=-1/2$ and define

$$x_1 = \Phi(x_0),\ x_2=\Phi(x_1),\ x_3 = \Phi(x_2),\ ...$$

in case the contraction property is fulfilled, the resulting sequence satisfies

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n = x^*$$

where $x^*$ is the solution to $x+e^x=0$.

Note that choosing a "right" starting value is important for this problem since $\Phi$ only fulfills the contraction property in a neighbourhood of $x^*$.

Comment: One could also add how to estimate the error of each iteration, i.e. how to estimate a priori how many iterations one needs to fulfil the "3 decimal places correctness". If $\theta$ is the contraction constant, you get $||x_k - x^*|| \leq \frac{\theta^k}{1-\theta} \cdot ||x_1 - x_0||$

Comment: Thank you so much, but how do you calculate it is -1/2?

Answer (score 0):

$e^X+X=0$ so we need the function $f(x)=-e^x$. Is it contractant?

If $f(X)=X$ , then $X$ must be negative since $e^x$ is always positive. Assuming this it follows that $f$ is contractant at the negative neighborhood of the fixed point $X$; in fact
$$|-e^{x_1}-(-e^{x_2}|=|e^{x_2}-e^{x_1}|=|x_2-x_1|\cdot|1+\frac{x_2+x_1}{2}+….|$$ so the last factor is $<1$

Furthermore the function $e^x+x$ is increasing and $e^0+0=1$ and $e^{-1}-1=-0.367879-1<0$ hence the fixed point $X$ is in the interval $[-1,0]$. 
Choosing  $x=-a$ we have successively $f(-a)=-e^{-a}$; $f(f(-a))=-e^{-e^{-a}}$;  $f(f(f(-a)))=-e^{-e^{-e^{-a}}}$;….

It seems to me the only way is to calculate the successive iterations till an approximation we consider adequate. Seeing at the graphs of $-e^x$ and $x$ we can see the point $X\approx 0.567$.